# I need docker instance to NOT utilize the host swap

Tags: docker, zfs, swapfile

My server build uses a lot of swap per container and I am told that docker uses the host swap for instances. My host ssd is only 256gb and is only intended to run the OS. I have setup a zfs pool (9 Tb and growing...) for docker and wanted it to use a portion of it for swap  since each instance needs 768k of swap and we plan on running 4k instances.

How can I configure docker to utilize some kind of custom zpool swap dedicated space?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply disable the swap?

1. Identify configured swap devices and files with cat /proc/swaps.
2. Turn off all swap devices and files with swapoff -a.
3. Remove any matching reference found in /etc/fstab.
4. Optional: Destroy any swap devices or files found in step 1 to prevent their reuse. Due to your concerns about leaking sensitive information, you may wish to consider performing some sort of secure wipe.
   man swapoff

(from here https://serverfault.com/questions/684771/best-way-to-disable-swap-in-linux)